# How to embed the category list in a mediawiki article?

Tags: mediawiki

Adding the `[[category:foo]]` tag to an mediawiki article causes that it will be added to a category list. 
How can I insert (embed) this list in an article. 
I tried to embed it with `{category:foo}` but this does not add the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [CategoryTree](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aCategoryTree) extension.  Once you've done that, you can insert a category into a page using either:

```
<categorytree>Foo</categorytree>
```

or:

```
{{#categorytree:Foo}}
```

Both syntaxes support a variety of parameters for customizing the category view; see the extension documentation page linked above for details.

Comment: CategoryTree is used (as the name suggests) to display category structures. If you (as I think is the case here) want to translude the category page to another page, you can use [DynamicPagelist](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicPageList) or [Semantic MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SemanticMediaWiki)